# How to add a pin code menu to Android TvSettings app's menus?

Tags: android

Need help to put some pin code menu with a numpad input on some menus in TvSettings(https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_TvSettings) like
Display, Apps, Developer Options.
If someone enters the wrong pin, the menus don't open.
Also put a build.prop device.model check inside the code so it asks for a pin if the app is used on another device.

Reference
https://blog.csdn.net/zcyxiaxi/article/details/119444898

Answer (score 0):

I've created PIN input for user login before.
I've used this 3rd party PIN view: https://github.com/cren90/PinLockView.

Here's some code that can put you on the right mind:

**PinFragment.kt**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
        setUpPinView()
    }

private fun setUpPinView() {
        binding.pinLockView.attachIndicator(binding.indicatorDots)
        binding.pinLockView.pinLockListener = object : PinLockListener {
            override fun onPinSubmit(pin: String) {
                Logger.d("Pin submit: $pin")
                mPinFragmentListener!!.onPinSubmit(pin)
            }

            override fun onComplete(pin: String?) {
                Logger.d("Pin complete: $pin")
                if (numberOfTimesPinComplete == 0) {
                    numberOfTimesPinComplete++
                    mPinFragmentListener!!.onPinComplete(pin)
                } else {
                    // empty input if pin was complete once before
                    binding.pinLockView.pin = ""
                    numberOfTimesPinComplete = 0
                }
            }

            override fun onEmpty() {
                Logger.d("Pin empty")
                numberOfTimesPinComplete = 0
            }

            override fun onPinChange(pinLength: Int, intermediatePin: String?) {
                Logger.d("Pin changed, new length $pinLength with intermediate pin $intermediatePin")
            }
        }
    }
```

**IntroActivity.kt**:

```
override fun onPinComplete(pin: String?) {
        Logger.i("IntroActivity onPinComplete()")
        login(pin)
    }

    override fun onPinSubmit(pin: String?) {
        Logger.i("IntroActivity onPinSubmit()")
        if (pin.isNullOrEmpty() || pin.length < 4 || pin.length > 4) {
            ToastUtils.updateError(this, getString(R.string.pin_incorrect_length))
        } else {
            login(pin)
        }
    }
```

**fargment_pin.xml**:

```
<com.cren90.pinlockview.Indicator
        android:id="@+id/indicatorDots"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:indicatorEmptyBackground="@drawable/indicator_empty"
        app:indicatorFilledBackground="@drawable/indicator_filled"
        app:indicatorSpacing="13dp"
        app:indicatorTextSize="24sp"
        app:indicatorTint="@color/white"
        app:indicatorType="fillWithValue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pinLockView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pinLockView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pinLockView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

<com.cren90.pinlockview.PinLockView
        android:id="@+id/pinLockView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:keypadButtonSize="65dp"
        app:keypadDeleteButtonTintColor="@color/primaryColor"
        app:keypadDeleteButtonDrawable="@drawable/ic_backspace_24dp"
        app:keypadDeleteButtonSize="20dp"
        app:keypadHorizontalSpacing="24dp"
        app:keypadShowSubmitButton="true"
        app:keypadSubmitButtonTintColor="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:keypadTextColor="@color/black"
        app:keypadTextSize="@dimen/key_text_size"
        app:keypadVerticalSpacing="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/indicatorDots"
        app:pinLength="4" />
```